# Can you connect HTML to FIREBASE

Tags: html, firebase

I have recently been working on some HTML I wanted to know how to connect HTML document to a
FIREBASE(firebase.google.com ).Can anyone please tell me how to connect HTML to FIREBASE .Please
if possible link GITHUB.

Thank you in advance,
Nishad.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to connect your HTML application to firebase you need to use backend language for that like JavaScript. Follow [this link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup) to do that.

Comment: Thank you so much i will surely check on that!

Comment: Good luck with your project!